# Youtube iframe "loop" doesn't work

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I tried to use the [YouTube player demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=zh-tw) to generate the code necessary for my video to autoplay and loop itself.
But only the autoplay works, it doesn't loop, and the demo-video doesn't work either. Here is the code I've used.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Try adding the `playlist`  parameter along with the loop. For playlist, set it's value as the current video id.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=M7lc1UVf-VE"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID
```

Reference:https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

Comment: Thank a million times. That worked. With the caveat that now you're supposed to use `&amp;` instead of `&`

Answer (score 16):

I just figured out you need to have `playlist=""` to use loop.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/peSfCy7HFrM?playlist=peSfCy7HFrM&loop=1;rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Answer (score 8):

Using in **react native** like this, make sure to use **same video ID value for playlist as well.**

for e.g if **video id is SpongeBOB**
then url will be like this :

https://www.youtube.com/embed/**SpongeBOB**?playlist=**SpongeBOB**&loop=1

below is implementation in **react native webview**

```
<WebView
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
  style={{ height:180, width:300,alignSelf:"center",alignContent:"center"}}
  source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/qD101Xlc5uw?playlist=qD101Xlc5uw&loop=1' }}
 />
```

Comment: This also worked just using an iframe. Note: The mute=1 parameter was mandatory for autoplay to work.    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vyl5oiNPOHY?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=Vyl5oiNPOHY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Answer (score 5):

```
'playlist': '<?php echo $youtube_video ?>'
```

inside playerVars.

For example a full code:

```
<script>
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height:'100%',
          width: '100%',
          fitToBackground: true,  
          videoId: '<?php echo $youtube_video ?>',
          playerVars: { 
              'autoplay': 1, 
              'controls': 0,
              'autohide':1,
              'enablejsapi':1,
              'loop':1, 
              'disablekb':1, 
              'fs': 0, 
              'modestbranding': 0, 
              'showinfo': 0, 
              'color': 'white', 
              'theme': 'light', 
              'rel':0  ,
              'playlist': '<?php echo $youtube_video ?>'
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        player.mute();
        player.setVolume(0);
        //player.setSize(1920, 1080);
        player.setLoop(true);
        player.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
      }
```

Your Html code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

If you want to keep video in a variable use this:

```
<?php $youtube_video='C0DPdy98e4c';?>
```

Comment: Confirm: this still works in 2021 using the [YouTube iframe player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&loop=1

note the playlist = VIDEO_ID is mandatory and is set to the video id for a single video

so in my case the url was

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/C5tG7pztlb0?playlist=C5tG7pztlb0&loop=1&autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&mute=1
```

mute is on
show info is off
show controls is off
autoplay is on
loop is on

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer didn't work for me either. Working workaround for September 2018 (bonus: set width and height by CSS for `#yt-wrap` instead of hard-coding it in JS):

```
<div id="yt-wrap">
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute(); // comment out if you don't want the auto played video muted
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(0);
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working example of an embedded and looping playlist:

```
<iframe width="1019" height="573" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLDz-3V1_TIyhVYiJeGdqc9bjpAf9L9Zfq&amp;loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay " ;"="" =""="" encrypted-media;="" gyroscope;="" picture-in-picture"="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```