# YouTube iframe not looping

Tags: iframe, youtube

I tried every single trick I could find and can't get this iframe to loop.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lalVmrRttVs?rel=0&;controls=0&;showinfo=0;loop=1&;autoplay=1&" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

http://www.montereycenter.org/energy-medicine/

Comment: Have you attempted HTML5 embedding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube iframe "loop" doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779966/youtube-iframe-loop-doesnt-work)