# Youtube parameters not working correctly

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I am having trouble getting a Youtube video to loop. I think my code is clean but it is not working as expected and I'm not sure why. My 'modestbranding' parameter is not working as I expect it to.

How can I get it to loop correctly?

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="header-video">
    <iframe id="vid-elem" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tl0x_zf8I78?loop=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube iframe "loop" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779966/youtube-iframe-loop-doesnt-work)

Comment: See [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop).

Comment: yeah i see it man thanks but the small problem is modestbranding parametres don't work because in the right bottom the logo youtube still appears and the loader before th video start .

Comment: That might be by design, but I'm not sure. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding) says "Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player."