# How to loop an iFrame video?

Tags: html

Trying to infinite loop a iFrame video.. Finding solutions that are mostly for youtube videos.. Any solution for an embedded video like the below?

```
<iframe src="https://embed.showcache.io/ptkFLE7sMONaS7YQ6PbtCM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen;" allowfullscreen loop></iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube iframe "loop" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779966/youtube-iframe-loop-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking: no, you cannot loop a video running in an `<iframe>`:

- You *can* control looping and playback of a `<video>` element through JavaScript, provided your page has permission to do (e.g. the `<video>` element is located in your own web-page and not in an `<iframe>`).
- But video-hosting sites' embedded-players are separate web-pages that are loaded into an `<iframe>` which will have a content-security policy that prohibits the parent web-page's scripts from interacting with the `<iframe>`'s content.

  - This sounds annoying or anti-competitive, but it's a good thing: otherwise any web-page you visit could hijack your YouTube account loaded into a hidden `<iframe>`.
- So if you're using a video-hosting site (e.g. Vimeo, YouTube, etc) then you won't be able to directly control their `<video>` elements from your own scripts.

  - However video-hosting sites tend to offer a client-side script API or SDK to allow for common video playback control tasks. e.g.:

    - YouTube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
    - Vimeo: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk
- If you run/operate/own the page loaded into the iframe, then you can set your own CSP, Cross-Origin, and cross-frame policy to allow for direct script access to embedded content to directly control `<video>` elements.

  - If you do this, you must exercise extreme caution and use an explicit allow-list of trusted `<iframe>` host-page origins (domain-names) rather than a wildcard.